# Advice on calculating the movement vector from an angle

Tags: math, vector, xna

I'm trying to calculate the movement vector (how much to change the x and y per frame) of a projectile given an angle.

I tried x = Acos(angle), y = Asin(angle) to get the values but the direction of the projectile movement never seems to match the angle.

Basically I want the projectile to travel as if it were fallowing a line.

I'm writing this in C# with the XNA framework, any and all advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
x=x0+v*cos(ang)*t
y=y0+v*sin(ang)*t
vx=v*cos(ang)
vy=v*sin(ang)
vx0=cos(ang)
vy0=sin(ang)
```

- x,y, is bullet position in time
- vx,vy is bullet speed vector
- vx0,vy0 is bullet direction unit vector
- x0,y0 is the bulet start position
- v is bullet speed
- t is time passed from the shoot beginig (at position x0,y0)
- ang is angle of the bullet (be sure angle is in the right units for sin,cos on your platform radians/degrees)
- if your angle does not match your screen coordinate system then you will have to invert one axis (usually y)

Comment: I think you should drop the `x0` and `y0` in your equation. Change to e.g. `x=v*cos(ang)`. The current projectile position has no relation to its velocity vector (in this case).

Comment: @Floris Yes as I wrote at the end of the answer I give the position equation because that is what he needs in the end anyway. and it is hard to say exactly what is movement vector for him ...

Comment: Then it still does not work. The incremental position vector is e.g. x=x+v*cos(ang) where you initialize x=x0.

Comment: @Floris oow I see it now I forget to add *t ... (I taught it was there ...I will edit in a second)

Comment: @user3243638 I see you are new user so ... if the question is answered check the check sign near the correct answer (it will give the author points and mark the solution for others to see it quickly) if it is only helpful in some way you can vote up by clicking on the upper triangle or if it is wrong harm-full abusive ... then you can vote down by that lower triangle (can cast only 1 vote per question or answer) also this will award you some badges I think ... also you can vote the comments if you have enough points. also all votes are undo-able so do not worry

Comment: @Spektre upvoted your question. Great answer. I have a small question, based on these values how do I determine the movement of the projectile. For, e.g. I am getting 123.5 (say) of x and 94.5 (say) of y values, how do I determine whether this would mean that the projectile is going right, straight or left? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Daqs not sure I get your question: You want to know direction the projectile is going? (inverse of above problem) then you need to know at least 2 positions in time of the projectile `p(t0)=(x0,y0)` and `p(t1)=(x1,y1)` let `t0<t1` so `p(t0)` is older position then `p(t1)` so `ang=atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)` now you have `<0-2PI> [rad]` or `<0,360> [deg]`  so you can easily check for any direction you want... you can recompute the speed also `v=sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0)+(y1-y0)*(y1-y0))/(t1-t0)`